# How do I make changes on a live Django website?

Tags: python, html, django, server, mapbox

I have a live Django website I need to make changes on and I want to know what's the best / most correct way of updating the code of the website, I have access to the remote server and access to the git.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you keep an updated git repository of your project on GitHub and commit to it often.

Then, when you are ready to publish your changes, pull your git repository down to your remote server. GitHub also allows you to keep a private repository for free now so no need to worry about confidentiality.